# Is font-awesome used to serve commercial webfonts?

Tags: css, html, fonts, font-awesome, webfonts

I have two related questions.  Is font-awesome used to serve commercial fonts, or just icons?  And either way, how many file(s) are needed to serve font(s) using font-awesome (file names are also welcome)?

As explanation: my client has a commercial webfont license on their website, and wants me to use it in an HTML5 'app' (interactive visuals) that will be embedded on their site.  I don't have access to their site / domain / server, but I need to provide the code so it will work with their font libraries.  They have given me this link to font-awesome and said that is all I need to do so.

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

I am pretty sure there must be at least one other CSS file needed, and maybe other details.  I am not the HTML5 developer myself, but I have a good handle on the technology of this and develop in several other software languages.  He is used to converting non-commercial fonts online, but not using this type of service.

I cannot find any docs or examples of font-awesome being used this way, pretty much only for icons.  I would really appreciate knowing exactly what to ask for, or even if they are giving me the right path to follow, since the corporate communication chain doesn't give me access to their web site developer.

Comment: Font-awesome is itself just a font, with appropriate CSS to access the font correctly to get icons. It is not a service for loading other fonts. Your client may be confused as to how that works.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I thought.  They have been insisting that it serves their licensed (Linotype.com / myfonts.com) web fonts, and that this link is all I need.

Comment: please check here http://fontawesome.io/license/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FontAwesome needs one css file and 6 font files.
The link above is a css which gets those 6 font files on that cdn server. (look at the top of that file)
You can embed that link or provide the files yourself by downloading them.

You can go to http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ and download it to see for yourself.